# /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt not found

Tags: 12.10, ssl, curl

I am using `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` to install RVM. I get an error saying

```
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

I searched a bit on the Internet and found that changing the permissions of `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` should get the job done. But whole `/etc/pki` directory is missing from my system. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On ubuntu/debian, this file is in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. You could symlink it. The `/etc/pki/` path is used on Redhat.

Comment: i have ubuntu 15.04 n faced the issue while installing the web app framework: meteor.js(curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh) I fixed it as you instructed. But which command or tool is looking for certificates in /etc/pki if this convention is going on for so many years?

Comment: Different Linux distributions use different paths. Debian uses one, RedHat another.

Comment: This saved my life! Tnx :)

Comment: can you please elaborate the steps? i am kind of lost as to what commands I have to enter in the terminal here.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a `~/.curlrc` file.

Then add the following lines to the file:

```
capath=/etc/ssl/certs/
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Feel free to adjust those paths as necessary, as different Linux distributions may use different paths.

(Worked for Ubuntu 14.04).