# RVM Installation error

Tags: rails

Trying to start a rails environment but it won't work. I'm following [installfest](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux) guide here. Steps 1 and 2 work; however, the `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` terminal command provides me with

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
XXX@XXX:~$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
-bash: /home/flyveren/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
XXX@XXX:~$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Following this, `type rvm | head -1` will give the output of `-bash: type: rvm: not found`, meaning the installation doesn't work at all.

The steps seem fairly straightforward but something is very wrong..

Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome 3 environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, do'h. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` worked, it appeared some ssl certificates were not up to date and that provided the error.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else lands here and updating doesn't help, this [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342484/etc-pki-tls-certs-ca-bundle-crt-not-found) helped me resolve the issue. Apparently it's a path issue.

So, quoting the answer from the link, simply create a `~/.curlrc` file and put in the file:

```
capath=/etc/ssl/certs/
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```